# Does a placeholder pseudo-element have pseudo-classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I want to animate appearance and disappearance of `placeholder` pseudo-element of an `input[type=text]`. My idea was to add styles (`transition`, in particular) to pseudo-classes of the former that are responsible for its presence (`:active` or something like that). So far, I haven't found any way to do that.

I tried to turn the placeholder pseudo-element into absolutely positioned block, but it didn't work. Several more tactics didn't lead to any meaningful result, either. Hence this question.

P.S. I have strong feeling that this is either prohibited by CSS3 specs or just not covered at all. Which is fine, but since there's [CSS4 coming one day](http://css4.rocks/), I believe my question will get a bunch of new answers along the way of history.

Answer (score 2):

> P.S. I have strong feeling that this is either prohibited by CSS3 specs or just not covered at all.

[Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-element-states) says that whether a pseudo-element can have user action pseudo-classes depends on the pseudo-element. Pseudo-Elements 4, which [defines the `::placeholder` pseudo-element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#placeholder-pseudo), does not comment on whether or not it can have pseudo-classes.

Based on this, you can therefore assume that this is prohibited by CSS3 specs. Which makes sense — you can't actually interact with a placeholder label in the first place, so having user action pseudo-classes on the `::placeholder` pseudo-element would be pointless.

Having said that, if you're trying to animate the appearance and disappearance of a placeholder when the *control* enters or leaves focus, you would attach pseudo-classes to the *control*, not the placeholder, and style the placeholder based on those states that the *control* is in.

*Even so*, Pseudo-Elements 4 (again) says that only properties that apply to `::first-line` may also apply to `::placeholder`, so you won't be able to animate it, nor can you change its display type or position it. So you're pretty much out of luck there either way.

> Which is fine, but since there's CSS4 coming one day

Except it's not. selectors-4 and css-pseudo-4 are CSS3 specs.